# HTML5 audio - recording saves file OK, but no sound when playing back through audio control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, audio, recording

I have an asp.net web application that allows a user to record audio.  I'm using code from https://github.com/nusofthq/Recordmp3js along with Matt Diamond's recorder files (modified for wav instead of mp3).  Not sure if it matters but I'm using the updated API for mediaDevices.getUserMedia().

The recording works fine, the wav file is saved to disk, and if I listen to the file on disk I can hear the recording.  However, if I try to play the audio back through the HTML5 audio control on the page, there is no sound.  The length of the file matches what is on disk so I don't think it's because the audio control is unable to find the file.

I can post my Javascript if that will be helpful.  I'm currently testing on localhost using Firefox.  Firebug doesn't show any errors.

Please let me know if any additional information may be helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: does it work on other browsers? does it play if you nav directly to the file?

Comment: I can hear the audio in Chrome, but not in Opera. Opera's web console doesn't show any errors. If I try to open the file directly in Firefox then I get prompted with what application to open the file with, I choose Firefox, and Firefox opens a new blank tab.  I tried a sample wav file I found online and the same behavior occurs (although .ogg files open fine inside Firefox).

Comment: since firefox can play wav files, it sounds like there is a minor issue with the file that chrome forgives but firefox doesn't.

Comment: I was wondering if it might be the files I'm recording, but I've tried a couple of sample wav files I found online; Firefox behaves the same way and simply opens a blank tab rather than playing them within the browser.  Perhaps I should be looking into Firefox and playing wav files since I know Firefox can play an ogg file OK?

Comment: i was thinking more in the <audio> tag.chrome might be special in that it plays full-tab. is the audio served over http, from the same site as the page?

Comment: Right now it's just on my localhost, but once in production it will be over https.  It was initially working in Firefox.  I just had a co-worker confirm he can hear the audio fine in Firefox, so I'm going to look into my FF configuration/install.

Comment: nothing jumps out at me, or apparently anyone else...

Comment: I appreciate your help though! :)  I'll post back once I figure out what's causing the issue.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

The (quickest) solution was to reset Firefox.  Wav files now play without any issues.